# window azure authentication in java

Tags: java, authentication, azure

window azure authentication in java...

```
String bingUrl = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?Query='multiple'&$top=4&$skip=1&$format=json";
String accountKey = "HEPgn2ahb407EMW/j5TXKs5umkO6VDlb8anWMq+O2=";
byte[] accountKeyBytes = Base64.encode((accountKey + ":" + accountKey).getBytes());
String accountKeyEnc = new String(accountKeyBytes);
URL urlb = new URL(bingUrl);
URLConnection urlConnection =urlb.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization","basic " + accountKeyEnc);
```

but this is not working...here account key is not actual

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question a while back and this code actually works: [Bing Search API Azure Marketplace Authentication in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136936/bing-search-api-azure-marketplace-authentication-in-java/11137385#11137385)

The first issue I'm seeing is that you are calling **Base64.encode**, this should actually be: **Base64.encodeBase64**. And could you also try changing **basic** to **Basic** (in the setRequestProperty call)?

These changes together with a correct account key should solve the issue.

Comment: Happy to hear everything works fine. Could you accept the answer then?

Comment: yes i accepted it.The answer you have provided is absolutely right