# Trying to connect to datamarket returns exception

Tags: java, azure, odata, olingo

I'm trying to connect to Azure data market, it's an odata repository. I'm using the latest Olingo library, r4.2.0.  The following code :

```
String serviceUrl = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/DataGovUK/MetOfficeWeatherOpenData/v1/";

ODataClient client = ODataClientFactory.getClient();
ODataServiceDocumentRequest req = client.getRetrieveRequestFactory().getServiceDocumentRequest(serviceUrl);
req.setAccept("application/json;application/xml;odata.metadata=full");
req.setContentType("application/json;application/xml;odata.metadata=full");
ODataRetrieveResponse res = req.execute();
```

returns an exception

```
 org.apache.olingo.client.api.communication.ODataClientErrorException: null [HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type]
```

The server returns :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<m:error mlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
   <m:code />
   <m:message xml:lang="en-US">
       Unsupported media type requested.
   </m:message>
</m:error>
```

Somebody tried to connect to Azure data market with this library or another with Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the request headers `Accept` & `Content-Type` with only `JSON` or `XML`, not both. Please see below.

```
req.setAccept("application/json");
req.setContentType("application/json;odata.metadata=full");
```

Or

```
req.setAccept("application/atom+xml,application/xml");
req.setContentType("application/atom+xml,application/xml;odata.metadata=full");
```

and for the authorization

```
req.addCustomHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + getAccountKey());
```

where account key as described in this other stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136936/bing-search-api-azure-marketplace-authentication-in-java) is:

```
public String getAccountKey()
{
    String accountKey = "My Microsoft Azure Account Key";
    byte[] accountKeyBytes = Base64.encodeBase64((accountKey + ":" + accountKey).getBytes());
    String accountKeyEnc = new String(accountKeyBytes);
    return accountKeyEnc;
}
```

Comment: Better, thanks. I'm getting now an 'HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized'. Any idea how to login with the 'Primary Account Key' ?

Comment: @ic3 You can refer to the answer for the SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136936/bing-search-api-azure-marketplace-authentication-in-java.